# Query or Table Refresh

Tags: ms-access

I have followed to help feature in access for refreshing a table or query by selecting the table or query I want to refresh then Records > Refresh.  Nothing is refreshing I have to close the table or query then reporn to see updates.  Im sure it is a simple solution, but it is not visible to me yet.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Refresh only refreshes the records shown in the current data set, i.e. any changes to the underlying records that you have already queried. It will not show new records or deleted records. This happens automatically anyway (refresh intervals in the Advanced Tab of Tools/Options).

You are confusing Refresh with Re-Query

Comment: So is there a way to have my query open make entrys to my table and requery without having to close and open?

Comment: Yes of course, simply add the "Run" command to one of your toolbars. i.e. Tools/Customize...Commands Tab, Category=Records. Find the Run Command and drag it to your toolbar. This will refresh your table and query.